# "Missing :action key on routes definition" in Rails 5

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I recently updated my rails from 4.1.5 to 5.1.2

My routes.rb file:

```
namespace :loading do
  get :index, action: :index
  root :to => :index
end
```

In 4.1.5 this works well. But after update to 5.1.2, I'm getting

```
Missing :action key on routes definition, please check your routes.
```

Please help me ;(

---

Solved.

replace

```
root :to => :index
```

to

```
root :action => :index
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to mention the `controller_name` with `action_name`

In 5.1.2, a Symbol will map directly to an `action` but you must also specify the `controller` to use.

Corrected routes:

## routes.rb

```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do
    namespace :loading do
      get :index => "loading_controller#index" #"controller_name#action_name"
      root :to => "loading_controller#index"
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.'root :to => :index' in :loading namespace is for route 'my_domain/loading' to 'loading_controller#index'

Comment: @KHLEE you can add root inside `namespace` and mention the `controller_name#action_name`

Comment: Is passing symbol to get/post deprecated?

Comment: @KHLEE Accept and vote answer if it works for you. Thanks

Comment: I found out the reason on rails doc. In 5.1.2, "a Symbol will map directly to an action but you must also specify the controller: to use:" . Thanks